# Does there exist a point $C$ for given two point $A$ an $B$ on a Jordan curve such that $ABC$ form a Isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan curve and suppose two arbitrary points $A$ and $B$ are given. Then does there exist a point $C$ on $\gamma$ such that $ABC$ form a Isosceles triangle with sides $AC=BC$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To find the point $C$ consider the bisector $s$ of the segment $AB$. The curve $\gamma$ joins $A$ and $B$. Since $\gamma$ is a Jordan curve, it must intersect $s$ at two or more points (because $A$ and $B$ are in different semiplanes with respect to $s$). Choose one of these points that does not lie on the segment $AB$ and you are done.